# How do I create a windowed python application

Tags: python

I am a beginner programmer and I've been programming for about 2 months now. It crossed my mind that most courses and tutorials teach python  by creating small apps in a python terminal or shell or something.
Is it possible to create a windowed application in python without using any libraries or frameworks other than the ones that come with python?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *without using any libraries* -- Nope.

Comment: Reword your question, how do you want do create anything useful without importing anything, no-library?

Comment: Top comment is flatly wrong. It is totally possible to create a windowed application in Python without using any libraries or frameworks. Simply pointlessly reimplement any one of the available libraries or frameworks and you will have a probably worse version _without using any libraries or frameworks_!

Comment: ... I concede defeat. ;)

Comment: Many (but not all) Python installation have [Tkinter](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter), which can be used to create GUIs. It's not fantastic, but it works. And because it's so common many people will be able to run your Python Tkinter programs without having to install anything. Bear in mind that it takes a while to master any GUI system because there's a lot to learn, with all the different objects that such a system provides, and the new programming techniques you will need to master.

Comment: Since the OP has reworded his question, I believe @PM2Ring's answer is closest. It is also good to note that while `Tkinter` works, it is vastly inferior to the likes of `PyQt` or `Enaml` for any serious development, but YMMV.

Comment: For doing simple graphical programs, you may enjoy exploring [turtle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/turtle.html), which uses Tkinter to do the actual graphics. Another popular way to do graphics (and sound) for games on Python is to use [Pygame](http://pygame.org/wiki/about) but that's generally not pre-installed with Python. Also, Pygame does _not_ provide full GUI capabilities (although I know a guy who's attempting to build a full GUI system that sits on top of Pygame...)

Comment: @TheLaughingMan: I disagree that Tkinter is _vastly inferior_. I wouldn't develop the next photoshop or itunes in it, but for most projects it is more than capable. It is a very pragmatic choice, especially when first learning GUI programming.

Answer (score 1):

The tkinter package (“Tk interface”) is the standard Python interface to the Tk GUI toolkit. Both Tk and tkinter are available on most Unix platforms, as well as on Windows systems.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/tkinter.html